# How to suppress indentation of first paragraph after heading?

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs, elsarticle

I am writing a document in a class (`elsarticle`) that indents the first lines of all paragraphs, including the ones following headings.  However, I would like to revert back to the default Latex behavior indenting all but the first paragraphs.

Of course I can do this manually using `\noindent`, but isn't there a better way?

Comment: This is a precise choice by the `elsarticle` class; if you're using it for submitting a paper, don't modify its behavior.

Comment: @egreg: Not to veer too much off-topic here, but… I am sure that they will change it back to their convention if they publish the paper.  But I dislike their convention and feel that I am entitled to chose my own for my preprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the internally used condition `\if@afterindent` for this indentation permanently to "false".

```
\documentclass[11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document

\makeatletter
\let\@afterindenttrue\@afterindentfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument  % drop in actual document
\end{document}
```

Note that the »[blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext)« package is only used for creating the dummy document here, thus is not part of the solution.

Comment: Umm, that looks line it removes indentation from more places than you would expect.