# Removing the indent of the first paragraph of a section (in French language)

Tags: indentation, french

I want to remove the indent just for the first paragraph of a section.
I am looking for an automatic solution. (I mean, it should be invisible for the "user", who does not have to type `no indent`)

I have tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mySection}[1]{\section*{#1}\noindent}

\begin{document}
\mySection{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But it does not work. There is a single space at the very beginning of the paragraph.

- Why is it so?
- And how can I achieve this?

Comment: Only from the first paragraph? Or all?

Comment: Only the first one.

Comment: You can use `\noindent` at the beggining of text.

Comment: No, I want to remove the indent just for the first paragraph.

Comment: Please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/4778 (the second answer suits your case I think.)

Comment: See the edit of my first comment.

Comment: I am looking for an automatic solution. So, it should be invisible for the "user", who does not have to type `noindent`.

Comment: That implies write in preamble?

Comment: @Alenanno, nope, `\usepackage{indentfirst}` does just the opposite.

Comment: @juanuni That implies to define a new command `\mySection` or modify the command `\section`... So, yeah, it implies writing in the preamble ;-)

Comment: @Colas If the package can set it to true, it can be set to false. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132369/4778

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of the linked question, which is *specific* about `elsarticle`.

Comment: The question is also about why the naive solution does not work.

Comment: if you start the paragraph prematurely with `\noindent` then the end of line following the heading will make a space unless you comment it out, also a blank line following the heading, which is normally correct markup would make a spurious paragraph.

Comment: Why does babel indent the first paragraph? Is this a french convention? A bug that became a feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}` to your preamble (p. 6 of the documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}

\begin{document}

\section{Zzzzz}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle, for your patience with my typos…

Comment: I love your sleepy sections!

Comment: mainly just clarifying that it worked with normal `\section` no need for user `\Section` wrapper.